# Magento secure and unsecure url redirection issue

Tags: magento-1.7, redirect, url-rewrite, https, htaccess

I am facing issue regarding redirection.

My system has been already live.Google already cached all pages with https .

In past my secure url and unsecured were both https://www.example.com.

```
But now 

secure url is https://www.example.com
unsecured  url is http://www.example.com
```

**Now, I  want to and trying to configure url like this**

```
checkout and customer urls are open   with https://www.example.com(Woking )
other all urls are open like http://www.example.com(Working)
```

**Issue:**

```
As my all pages are cached as https in google so,
my other all urls are open with https
```

**But,i want to redirect https non checkout and non customer  url to http
Using htaccess**

**all pages is cache in google with https.That if an non-customer/non-checkout url is coming with https, then it should be redirect to http**

Here, i have done the following changed  in admin:

```
Base URL>secure url>https://www.abc.com
Base URL>unsecure url>http://www.abc.com
Use Secure URLs in Frontend=yes
```

Comment: There is NO need to do this. https is just fine for everything.

Comment: Thanks,But Fabian ,as i said the all pages is cache in google with https.That if an non-customer/non-checkout url is coming with https, then it should be redirect to http

Comment: If your settings are correct, once the customer lands on the page with a https:// in the URL, all links on the site to non customer/checkout pages will be http://, Google should naturally resolve the issue.

Comment: Fabian,please check question .i have put up my admin setup

Comment: Yes.As of my knowledge, whenever you made the changes in your application and when an user visits this page, the google cache will check with your current settings. If the comparision of cache fails, then new settings will be copied to google. But effecting of this changes will take minimum 2-3hrs. If you made everything fine, then no need to worry of google cache.

Comment: I guess the default behavior of Magento is, it uses https for secure pages only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i use cloudflare  and it redirection logic is different

To redirect a user from HTTP to HTTPS, you can use the following:

```
  RewriteCond %{HTTP:CF-Visitor} '"scheme":"http"'
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.com/$1 [L]
```

When using Flexible SSL with CloudFlare, your origin server will always accept requests over HTTP (port 80). In order to properly redirect a user surfing securely over HTTPS, you should modify your rewrite rules to use the CF-Visitor HTTP header. The CF-Visitor header contains the following:

```
CF-Visitor: {"scheme":"http"}
```

or
    CF-Visitor: {"scheme":"https"}

To redirect a user from HTTP to HTTPS, you can use the following:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:CF-Visitor} '"scheme":"http"'
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.com/$1 [L]
```

Similarly, to require all traffic go over HTTPS on CloudFlare, you can use the following:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:CF-Visitor} !'"scheme":"http"'
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.com/$1 [L]
```

Comment: I have applied above code to .htaccess file but not working. any other setting require for it ?

Comment: already mentaion,,, it only work when cloudflare is enabled

Comment: @AmitBera Can you help me with  https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/221741/magento-skip-https-redirect

Answer (score 2):

This code for solved this problem

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on


RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$
RewriteRule ^(shop|blog|stockists|inthepress|contacts|review|home) http://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^$ http://%{HTTP_HOST} [L,R]
```

Thanks!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

I actually combat this using a core controller over-ride.  Without this, Google could in-theory penalise you for duplicate content as it will see the HTTPS AND HTTP versions of your site, having the same content.  I've written a blog post on it, but I've not posted it yet - but basically, Magento includes the functionality to redirect you to a HTTPS page when required (i.e. checkout, account area etc) however, it doesn't provide the opposite.

This approach has the added benefit of not needing to alter your .htaccess file each time that you add a new secure URL.  It also means, you don't miss anything.

The function is called in `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php`.  Luckily, as this is a Controller file, it means that we can copy it to our local folder, and over-ride the method.  So, copy `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php` to `app/code/local/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php`.

In Magento 1.7 and 1.8, you need to look at the function `_checkShouldBeSecure` - around line 427 of your newly copied file.

Alter this function to:

```
protected function _checkShouldBeSecure($request, $path='')
{
    if (!Mage::isInstalled() || $request->getPost()) {
        return;
    }

    if ($this->_shouldBeSecure($path) && !Mage::app()->getStore()->isCurrentlySecure()) {
        $url = $this->_getCurrentSecureUrl($request);

        Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()
            ->setRedirect($url)
            ->sendResponse();
        exit;
    } elseif (!$this->_shouldBeSecure($path) && Mage::app()->getStore()->isCurrentlySecure()) {
        $url = $this->_getCurrentUnsecureUrl($request);

        Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()
            ->setRedirect($url)
            ->sendResponse();
        exit;
    }
}
```

Now, add the function:

```
protected function _getCurrentUnsecureUrl($request)
{
    if ($alias = $request->getAlias(Mage_Core_Model_Url_Rewrite::REWRITE_REQUEST_PATH_ALIAS)) {
        return Mage::getBaseUrl('link', false).ltrim($alias, '/');
    }

    return Mage::getBaseUrl('link', false).ltrim($request->getPathInfo(), '/');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify your .htaccess file something like below

> ```
>    RewriteEngine On
>     RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
>     RewriteEngine On
>
>     # From https to http
>     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/checkout/onepage/
>     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/customer/account/
>     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/checkout/multishipping/login/
>     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wishlist/
>     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php/admin/dashboard/index/key/
>     RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
> ```

And set "Auto-redirect to Base URL" to NO under System -> Configuration -> Web -> Url Options

You can go through articles on Google how to redirect from https to http for more detailed information.
Hoping this will give you some help.

Comment: admin other url create the issue

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get your point.