# Magento Skip HTTPs redirect

Tags: magento-1.9, redirect

I am using following code

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/healthy-library

# First rewrite to HTTPS:
# Don't put www. here. If it is already there it will be included, if not
# the subsequent rule will catch it.
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]


# Now, rewrite any request to the wrong domain to use www.
# [NC] is a case-insensitive match
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/healthy-library
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

I want to skip the HTTPS redirect for this url http://www.sitename.com/healthy-library. Using the above code, it redirects to https://www.sitename.com/index.php

Any thoughts what could be wrong here?